# How to open a Project in NetBeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, project

Hi guys I just clean and build my project in Netbeans, copy the folder of my project, put it in a ZIP archive and send it to myself. Now I don't know how to deploy the project, I tried just to copy the classes and run it, but it give me so many error, even if I try to recreate the structure of the packages with the same name it doesn't work. I tried to find information on the internet but is not very clear.

When I click on Clean and Build.

NeatBeans create a folder with the name of the project and inside> build,dist,nbproject,src,web,build

Comment: "it give me so many error" ... you see why we can't give any clear response on that?

Comment: I tried to find information in your question, but it is not very clear either. What kind of project is it, what is its structure, what is contained in your zip, how do you import it in Netbeans, what are the errors? *"Doesn't work" doesn't help*.

Comment: Sorry my friend my question was how to open a project, the error is "cannot find the symbol", when I create the package and then put the name of the package and . , it doesn't show auto complete. My question is how to deploy a project after the clean and build option from Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

When you clean and build under Netbeans, you should find all you need under the `dist` folder:

- if you a creating a web application you should find a .war file - that is the file to deploy: just copy it to the `webapps` folder for Tomcat
- if you are creating a standalone application or a library, you should find the .jar

Above assume you do not use maven for the project. If you did you would not have a `dist` folder, but the standard maven `target` one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what are the errors you get. However check these few things out and see if it works for you:

check if you are importing from an external Library, if so, make sure that you have those libraries within your project.

If you are creating a new project and just copy pasting the classes, then make sure packages are correct and not from the other project you had.

it is pretty simple to open a project in net beans:

1. after creating your project and building it, zip the whole project folder.
2. once you unzipped it, use "CTRL+Shift+O" or the third option in netbeans>file to open a project.
3. a filechooser should open and you can select the project you want to open.

this is pretty much the whole thing you need to do.

you can also find the .war in webapps folder,  .jar in dist folder too.

your question is really unclear. We dont know what is your project exactly nor your errors.
Please let me know the exact errors. so that I can help you with better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what is the error your facing but I think that  if you use the export and import project features of NetBeans maybe you wouldn't have that error in the first place:

To export project: 
go to File -> Export Project -> To ZIP... -> Specify the zip destination directory.

To import project:

go to File -> Import Project -> From ZIP... -> And browse your file system to find the zip you previously created.